# Set up Grid in Swing JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I created a GUI with Swing in IntelliJ, which looks like this:

[image]

Below the `JTextField` are the `JPanel`s (top: `gridPlayerOne`, bottom: `gridPlayerTwo`) and I want to a grid within the `JPanel`s: `gridPlayerOne` and `gridPlayerTwo`.

```java
public class GameBoard extends JFrame{
    private JButton stop;
    private JButton start;
    private JTextField playerOne;
    private JPanel gridPlayerOne;
    private JPanel gridPlayerTwo;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField1;

    public GameBoard(){
        add(contentPane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameBoard gameBoard = new GameBoard();
        gameBoard.setTitle("BattleShip");
        gameBoard.pack();
        gameBoard.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gameBoard.setSize(700,500);
        gameBoard.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        gameBoard.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I tried to paint the Grid with `void paint(Graphics g)`, but I'm not sure how to declare paint to two `JPanel`s.

My problem is that i dont know to how to draw a grid within gridPlayerOne & gridPlayerTwo:

[image]

Comment: yes. I mean i could paint them with `public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        for ( int x = 25; x <= 100; x += 25 )
            for ( int y = 25; y <= 100; y += 25 )
                graphics.drawRect( x, y, 25, 25 );
    }`

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/

Comment: I updated my question. I know to to paint a grid, but im not sure how to paint it inside my JPanels: gridPlayerOne & gridPlayerTwo

Comment: Lots of people have already created a _Battleships_ game with Swing. Did you try searching for ___java swing battleship game___?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870396/how-to-paint-a-gridline-as-a-background-on-jpanel

Comment: Don't post code in a comment. The code is not readable. You should NOT be overriding paint(). Custom painting is done by overriding paintComponent. You also need to invoke super.paintComponent() to make sure the background is cleared.